# Can't find 8GB data in FreeBSD

Tags: mount, freebsd, disk-usage, ufs

I can't find 8GB data in FreeBSD.  I use `df -h` and see this:

```
/dev/da1s1a      19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /
devfs            1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
zzdata/jail      341G     22G    318G     7%    /jail
ssd/radius       183G     10G    173G     5%    /jail/mysql1/var/db/mysql/radius
ssd              173G     31k    173G     0%    /ssd
zzdata           355G     37G    318G    10%    /usr/local
zzdata/ports     319G    906M    318G     0%    /usr/ports
zzdata/ports/distfiles    319G    457M    318G     0%    /usr/ports/distfiles
zzdata/src       318G    386M    318G     0%    /usr/src
/bin             19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/bin
/sbin            19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/sbin
/lib             19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/lib
/libexec         19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/libexec
/usr/bin         19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/bin
/usr/sbin        19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/sbin
/usr/include     19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/include
/usr/lib         19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/lib
/usr/libdata     19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/libdata
/usr/libexec     19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/libexec
/usr/share       19G     16G    1.4G    92%    /jail/mysql1/usr/share
/usr/ports       319G    906M    318G     0%    /jail/mysql1/usr/ports
/usr/ports/distfiles   319G  457M  318G   0%    /jail/mysql1/usr/ports/distfiles
devfs            1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /jail/mysql1/dev
fdescfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev/fd
```

I try to check via `du -Aclnx` all files mounted to UFS filesystem and nonetheless I find 9525Mb files.  Any suggestion?

My fstab:

```
/dev/da1s1a / ufs rw 1 1
/dev/da1s1b none swap sw 0 0
10.199.194.110:/storage/xfs_radius /mnt/nas nfs rw,tcp,noauto,noatime,async 0 0
```

Comment: Where are you getting the "8GB" figure from?  Are all of the file systems in your `df` output UFS?

Comment: I checked every directory which belong to /.No,I have zfs also (zzdata),here is my fstab output`

/dev/da1s1a     /               ufs     rw      1       1

/dev/da1s1b     none            swap    sw      0       0

10.199.194.110:/storage/xfs_radius /mnt/nas    nfs rw,tcp,noauto,noatime,async 0 0

Comment: So are you looking for a file that is 8GB?  A collection of files that equate to 8GB?  Or are you looking to free up 8GB worth of space?  In your question you haven't really specified what you want to do/what the problem is

Comment: Sorry for my bad Englsh))
When I use df I see that /dev/da1s1a filesystem mounted on / and have 19831Mb size.From which 16829Mb is used and 1415 is available.But I can't found this 16829Mb files via du.I checked every directory in which mounted on /, and sum of these files is 9525Mb.I don't understatnd where are  7304Mb of files.I try to found also deleted files via lsof.

Comment: OK, I understand :) Does `lsof` show any large files open?  It could be that a process opened a file and the file has since been deleted but the process is still running.

Comment: root@cbx:/ # lsof -a +L1 /     shows
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF NLINK    NODE NAME
tail    41577 root    1w  VREG   0,98 8840409518     0 2087444 / (/dev/da1s1a)
tail    54128 root    3r  VREG   0,98   22356268     0 1687264 / (/dev/da1s1a)

I found,thank you very much.

/dev/da1s1a                19G    8.2G    9.6G    46%    /       :D

Comment: Brilliant :D  I've included a summary in an answer, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: You should **[edit]** your question to include additional information requested in comments. That will make it significantly easier to read, and all information relevant for answering the question will remain in a single place. Comments are subject to deletion at any time for almost any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a process opens a file but the file is then deleted, the output of `du` will be different to `df`.

You can use `lsof` in order to find processes open with files that are around the size you are missing.

When the process ends/closes the file, `df` and `du` should show the same space used.